# Maxlength TextArea HTML5 bug?

Tags: html, textarea, maxlength

When I set the maxlength of a textarea to 700, and paste a lorem ipsum text (which is greater then 700 chars) in the textarea, the textarea contains 704 chars when counting at http://string-functions.com/length.aspx. Is this a bug or...?

```
<textarea maxlength="700"></textarea>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bpyds1gd/

### update

replace the blank line to a new line: `preg_replace("/(^[rn]*|[rn]+)[st]*[rn]+/", "\r" , $string)`
then replace the new line to a break: `echo(nl2br($string))` for html output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not 704 chars, it is 700 chars if you delete enter chars

Comment: your text has 2 enter. If you copy and paste lorem ipsum text, You should remove enters

Comment: Yes, so I don't want to remove those 2 enters, but the text should be not more then 700 chars included the enters

Comment: why not. enter key is \n

Comment: Thanks!, solved the problem, updated the first post.